# How will the graduate committee regard two different TOEFL or GRE scores sent to them?

Tags: graduate-admissions, gre, toefl

Suppose a student gets two GRE and toefl scores and he can't decide which scores are more suitable for sending, so he sent all of them anyway. The students may want to decide recipients of their scores even before they know their scores just to save money(ETS allows up to 4 free recipients but they must be decided before or on test dates).

His scores are:

GRE

> V 152 Q 168 AW 3.5
>
> V 158 Q 164 AW 3.0

The student improved his score a lot in verbal reasoning and dropped in Quantitative Reasoning and analytical writing since he focused too much on the preparation of verbal reasoning.

TOEFL

> Reading 29 listening 27 Oral 20 Writing 25
>
> Reading 27 listening 24 Oral 24 Writing 25

The total score of the first one is greater but the second one is better in speaking session, which is important for getting TAships.

My question is, in such cases, how will the graduate committee consider this student's scores. Will they feel annoyed by having to look at two ETS transcripts? Will they only look at the latest scores?

Comment: Who knows? There isn't some universal set of rules that graduate committees follow.  They are comprised of people, and different people may have different opinions.  Some might think the latest scores are the most meaningful, and ignore the others.  Some might think the earlier scores are more representative of the applicant's true abilities, and later increases are just cramming.  Some might look at the trend.  Some might average them.  Some might look at whichever is higher, or whichever is lower.  There's no way to answer your question.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks! I think your comment is a fine answer. But I have to say it is unfair to look at the lower scores since many students never send their bad scores as long as their don't care about the money

Answer (score 0):

This mainly depend on what department you want to send application, for match,cs etc the quantitative reasoning is main interest for english, literature history the verbal and writing skills matter. Also if they are asking score as total and also for each module then its easy however some universities doesnot say about how they weight GRE score

As for toefl it also depends on the criteria set by the university e.g they can ask a total score of x with no less then y in each module. As when i was applying it was actually ielts and mentiones that ielts band 7 is required with no module less then 6.5, so if your score is crossing in any results the minimum criteria you can apply using that